# Расчет характеристик элементов электрич. цепи, зная ее структуру и все сопротивления

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру по физике, где в одном из режимов игрок может строить электрические цепи из *проводов, резисторов, ключей* и т.д.

> Я знаю, как создать само "построение" цепи, т.е. чтобы, например, резистор одним своим концом примагничивался к проводу, который к нему присоединен.

Что я **не знаю** как сделать -- это "течение тока". Любой элемент цепи обладает **силой тока, напряжением и неизменным сопротивлением**, связанных формулой `I=U/R`. Так вот мне надо уметь расчитывать силу тока и напряжение на каждом элементе цепи.

У меня есть идея такой реализации:

1. Цепь -- граф, хранится как список смежности, где для каждого элемента указано, какой/какие следующие за ним в цепи.
2. Каждый элемент имеет неизменное сопротивление, не зависящее ни от чего.
3. Источника тока выдает ток силой I (характеристика источника).
4. Далее идет расчет силы тока и напряжения для всех участков цепи по порядку согласно списку смежности.

Тут появляется загвоздка: если все соединено **последовательно**, ты мы можем легко все рассчитать, так как сила тока неизменна и, зная сопротивление, можно найти напряжение, **НО** если ток **распараллеливается**, то сила тока на каждой ветви разная + мне непонятно, как найти в какой точке ветви вновь сходятся.

Повторюсь, что нужно уметь рассчитывать силу тока и напряжение на каждом элементе цепи, зная сопротивление каждого элемента и структуру цепи.

---

*Так как SO не любит, когда ТС ничего не сделал сам, то у меня есть такой код для **последовательного** сопротивления*

```
public class CircuitElement // Любой элемент цепи
{
    public readonly float Resistance;
    private List<CircuitElement> Successors;

    public CircuitElement (float resistance, List<CircuitElement> successors)
    {
        Resistance = resistance;
        Successors = successors;
    }

    public void AddSuccessor (CircuitElement succ)
    {
        Successors.Add(succ);
    }
    public void RemoveSuccessor (CircuitElement succ)
    {
        if (Successors.Contains(succ))
            Successors.Remove(succ);
    }

    public List<CircuitElement> GetSuccessors ()
    {
        return Successors;
    }
}

public class CommonElement : CircuitElement // Любой элемент кроме источника (имеет напряжение и силу тока)
{
    private float amperage, voltage;
    public float Amperage
    {
        get => amperage;
        set
        {
            amperage = value;
            voltage = amperage * Resistance;
        }
    }
    public float Voltage
    {
        get => voltage;
        set
        {
            voltage = value;
            amperage = voltage / Resistance;
        }
    }

    public CommonElement(float resistance, List<CircuitElement> successors)
        : base(resistance, successors) { }
}

public class PowerSource : CircuitElement // Источник тока
{
    public readonly float Amperage;

    public PowerSource(float resistance, float amperage, List<CircuitElement> successors)
        : base(resistance, successors)
    {
        Amperage = amperage;
    }
}

public class Circuit // Цепь
{
    List<CircuitElement> Elements;

    public Circuit (List<CircuitElement> elements)
    {
        Elements = elements;
    }

    public void CalculateCurrent ()
    {
        // Список Elements строится таким образом, что нулевой элемент -- всегда источник тока
        float amperage = ((PowerSource)Elements[0]).Amperage;

        var firstElement = Elements[0];
        var currElement = Elements[1];
        do
        {
            ((CommonElement)currElement).Amperage = amperage;

            var successors = currElement.GetSuccessors();
            if (successors != null)
                currElement = successors[0];

        } while (currElement != firstElement);
    }
}
```

Это пока просто математическая модель.
*Источник тока в цепи по замыслу игры всегда один.*

Comment: Для меня до сих пор остаётся загадкой, как работает всякое ПО вроде Matlab Simulink или Multisim. Вы, по сути, изобретаете свою версию такого физического симулятора. Я бы попробовал поискать какие-нибудь библиотеки для симуляции и начать с них.

Answer (score 2):

Первый закон Кирхгофа - в каждом узле сумма токов (втекающие с плюсом, вытекающие с минусом) равна нулю.

Второй закон - падение напряжений на замкнутом контуре равно нулю, или ЭДС
источника равна падению напряжений на остальной части контура.

Таким образом, строится система линейных уравнений (типа `i1+i2+i3=0, r1*i3+r5*i4+r7*i5=0, Ubat = i1*r1+i*r2` и т.д.)

Легко ли программно определить достаточный набор контуров, узлов и соответственно уравнений - не знаю, в школе мы руками делали (для контуров, например, есть алгоритмы поиска базисных циклов графа)

Comment: Таким образом задача сведётся к составлению и решению системы уравнений, насколько я понимаю? А что вы обозначили за `Ubat`?

Comment: Да, верно, к решению системы для нахождения токов и напряжений. Но вот подготовить исходные данные для построения системы - может быть не очень просто. Ubat - ЭДС батареи при её наличии  в контуре.

Comment: вообще не планировал делать уровни с несколькими контурами. Сейчас целевая задача -- цепи уровня 8 класса: источник, ключ, амперметр, вольтметр, резисторы/реостаты и "провода". Спасибо за подсказку. Попробую

Comment: Так если у вас не только последовательное соединение, а, например, [мост Уитстона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82), то в нём уже два контура есть. Ваш вопрос же и был в том, что делать с распараллеливанием токов.